# Microsoft Dynamics: Value of the field shows on the form, but it doesnt show on the grid view

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, field, microsoft-dynamics

I have an issue with the visibility of value of the field. I'm using MS Dynamics CRM. After I code the field, in the form, the value of this field shows up perfectly. However, it doesn't turn up on the view.

I have tried, `onSave`, `onLoad`, `read-only` etc. and it just doesn't work. I also have debugged it, and there was no error. I have no idea what the problem is.

Code:

```
function change_currentstatus() {
    var chk0 = document.getElementById('new_pc1');
    var chk1 = document.getElementById('new_m1');
    var chk2 = document.getElementById('new_m2');
    var chk3 = document.getElementById('new_m3');
    var chk4 = document.getElementById('new_m4');
    var txt = document.getElementById('new_currentstatus');
    if(!chk4.checked == false) {
        txt.value = 'm4';
    } else if(!chk3.checked == false) {
        txt.value = 'm3';
    } else if(!chk2.checked == false) {
        txt.value = 'm2';
    } else if(!chk1.checked == false) {
        txt.value = 'm1';
    } else if(!chk0.checked == false) {
        txt.value = 'pc1';
    } else {
        txt.value = ' ';
    }
}
```

Maybe something is wrong with the settings, or the JavaScript.

Comment: Is the field read only on the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first observation is: Use the CRM 2011 javascript object model, take a resume [here](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/01/14/crm-2011-useful-javascript-tidbits/). So for read a field use this:

```js
var varMyValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("CRMFieldSchemaName").getValue();
```

To set a value:

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("po_CRMFieldSchemaName").setValue('My New Value');
```

So you have to change this code:

```js
if(!chk4.checked == false)
    txt.value = 'm4';
```

Replace with this:

```js
if(!Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_m4").getValue() == false)
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_currentstatus").setValue('m4');
```